# Trying to write a binary file, getting a text file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

Trying to save my game by writing the game characters to a binary file.  Unfortunately, my binary file is writing to the file as if it were a text file.

If I just instantiate a string and call the save function for the string, it writes to the binary file perfectly. However, if I call the same function from my CharacterSave function -- it just displays the file as a text file instead of a binary one.

The call hierarchy goes

1. Character.Save() calls the string save, which writes to a binary file.
2. Character.Save() calls the pouch (i.e. coinpouch) save, which writes to the binary file.
3. Character.Save() calls the purse (i.e. backpack) save, which calls the dynamic array save, which writes the number of elements to a binary file and calls the potion save method, which calls the string save method.

**EDIT: Solved the problem.  I don't know how, but just making another .dat file solved it.**

**Call to save function**

```
//Create instance of binary file object
std::ofstream file("game.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

//Check if file is open
if(file.is_open())
{
    //Save character
    myFavoriteCharacter.Save(file);

    //Close the file
    file.close();
}
else
    std::cout << "\nFile did not open! " << std::endl;
```

**Character save function**

```
void Character::Save(std::ofstream & file)
{
    mName.Save(file);
    mPouch.Save(file);
    mPurse.Save(file);
}
```

**String save function**

```
void String::Save(std::ofstream & file)
{
    int tempLength = 0;
    tempLength = this->getLength();

    //Write the length of the string
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tempLength), sizeof(int));

    //Write the string
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(this->mStr), tempLength + 1);
}
```

**CoinPouch (i.e. pouch) save function**

```
void CoinPouch::Save(std::ofstream & file)
{
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&mPlatinum), sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&mGold), sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&mSilver), sizeof(int));
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&mCopper), sizeof(int));
}
```

**DynamicArray save function**

```
void DynamicArray::Save(std::ofstream & file)
{
    //Write the number of elements
    file.write(reinterpret_cast <char *>(&mElements), sizeof(int));

    //Save each element
    for(int i = 0; i < mElements; i++)
        mArray[i].Save(file);
}
```

**Potion save function**

```
void Potion::Save(std::ofstream & file)
{
    mName.Save(file);
    mDescription.Save(file);
    mPotency.Save(file);
    mCost.Save(file);
}
```

Comment: You are mostly saving character data. Character data looks the same in text or binary. So what are you seeing that makes you sure that this file is text not binary? Not to put too fine a point on it, but what you saying seems impossible.

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong in your code (but there is of course a whole load of stuff missing, that could be wrong, inconsistent or otherwise). I'm curious however, how you determine that the file is "not a binary file". All files are binary, text-files just happen to have ONLY printable values of 'char' and a small set of control characters (newline, tab and a couple of others). If you print the output from your code as a file to the screen, I'd expect to see mainly text strings, since that appears to be what you are saving...

Comment: @Mats Petersson -- I don't know how, but I changed "game.dat" to "game2.dat" (i.e. forcing it to open a new file) and it worked.  My code is now saved in a binary format as opposed an ASCII (i.e. text) format.  Maybe it was a Visual Studio thing?

Comment: @john When you write a binary file, Visual Studio creates a hex dump of the file.  You see the address lines in hex for the first column.  The actual bytes of the code for the second column.  Then the actual text for the third column.  The above was just printing out the text.

Comment: Maybe you need "std::ios::trunc" to truncate (make the size zero) the file before writing to it?

Comment: @MrPickle5 Like MatsPetersen says there really no such thing as a text file. All files are binary files. What VS is doing is making a *guess* at how to display the file, based on the file extension or on the file contents. Your code has been working all along, some of VS guesses at how best to display the file have been different that's all.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I believe std::ios::out uses std::ios::trunc by default unless I specify std::ios::app/ate/in.

Answer (score 1):

Forced Visual Studio 2012 to open a new file called "game2.dat" and it worked.  There is now a hex dump of my binary file, instead of the normal text file it was giving me.  So weird and I do not really understand why this, but it did.

Thanks to those who read/responded.

Comment: The name of the file obviously doesn't alter whether it is written to as a binary file or text file. If I force the compiler to generate it's binary output to a file called "foo.txt", it will still be binary. There is something wrong in your code, and I think it is that you are not opening a NEW file.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Why do I need a new file?  Doesn't ofstream overwrite everything in the old file?

Comment: No, you're right, it creates a new file based on the arguments you've already given. So the explanation above about MS guessing the content of the file is probably right, and it may just be that you saves some slightly different data that triggered the difference in "how visual studio opens the file".